Express a dot product of an undecomposable vector with a dot product with tensor vectors.
I've been struggling for few hours on this.
Context :
$\mathbb{F}$ is finite field.
$w$ is in $\mathbb{F}^{k\times k}$
$\langle .,.\rangle$ is the common dot product.
Question :
For any $x\in \mathbb{F}^{k\times k}$, is there $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{F}^{k}$ such that
$$\langle w,x \rangle = \langle w,x_1\otimes x_2 \rangle$$
I know that there exists vectors that cannot be written in $x_1\otimes x_2$ form.
Have you ever heard of this result ? If it is wrong, do you have an example ?

Let $\alpha = \langle w,x\rangle$. Choose $x_1',x_2$ such that $\beta=\langle w, x_1'\otimes x_2\rangle \ne 0$. Now set $x_1 = \frac\alpha\beta x_1'$. Then $x_1,x_2$ is your pair of vectors.
The only way for there to not be such $x_1'\otimes x_2$ is for $\langle w,x\rangle = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb F^{k{\times}k}$. If you're using the standard bilinear form on $\mathbb F^k$, then this is impossible unless $w=0$.
